# Download app from iPad to iPod touch with different Apple ID

Tags: ios-appstore, apple-id

How do I download a purchased app on iPad to an iPod touch with a different Apple ID?
My daughter purchased an app and put it on her iPad, and I want to put it on an iPod touch that I gave my grandson with my Apple ID.  It won't let us do that.

Answer (score 1):

Correct, it won't let you do that.

You'd need to re-purchase it on the other ID, or investigate [Family Sharing](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT201060?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) - one credit card, multiple family members, multiple account IDs, shared apps & content, with Parental Control.